# `error: object B is not a case class` - but `B` is a case class

Tags: scala

Given two Algebraic Data Types: `A` and `Foo`:

```
scala> sealed trait A
defined trait A

scala> case object B extends A
defined object B

scala> sealed trait Foo
defined trait Foo

scala> case class FooImpl(x: Int) extends Foo
defined class FooImpl
```

a simple function `f`:

```
scala> def f: Foo = FooImpl(5)
f: Foo
```

Finally, I have a few nested `match` statements/expressions:

```
scala> def hoobar(x: A): Int = x match {
     |            case B(_) => f match {
     |              case FooImpl(_) => ???
     |            }
     |           }
<console>:18: error: object B is not a case class, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq member
                  case B(_) => f match {
                       ^
```

Why does the above error show up? `B` is certainly a `case class`, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`B` is a case object, not a case class. `B(_)` doesn't make sense. What would `_` be a substitution for when there is only one object `B`?

If you want to match on `B`, a specific object, use (back-ticks required if lower-case):

```
case B => ...
```

Though you *could* get the other syntax to work by providing an `unapply` method for `B`, it just doesn't really make sense.

```
case object B extends A {
    def unapply(b: this.type): Option[this.type] = Some(b)
}
```

Comment: Yep - my mistake, thanks, @m-z and 0__. I was trying to reproduce an error in my code where I'm getting that error, but the value is actually a case class.